# Fastest key value nosql database

Tags: database, caching, nosql

For a caching application - what nosql (key => value) database would be the fastest in terms of both reading a writing?

Redis, Casandra etc or something else?

Comment: Why are you using a "nosql" database for caching? Why not something like memcached?

Comment: Hazelcast was another cool tool that was demo'ed at a JUG I went to recently.  "HazelCast can be used for distributed, elastic caching, and distributed tasks and queries across that distributed data."  http://www.hazelcast.com/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Redis and Cassandra are leaders when you need to write to disk.
For pure in-memory (obviously the fastest) go with Infinispan.

[Disclaimer: I contributed myself to Infinispan. Was pretty awesome to deal with the speed improvements though]